# Basic steps to create deep linking in Android

Tags: android

I am creating deep linking in my android app.

Can you please tell me how to implement deep linking and Android indexing.

I have already gone through android developer website but could not understand .

Answer (score 1):

Create an activity where you will handle the intent that will come to your app when clicking on the external links. Register your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml with the scheme/slug for your links so that Android recognize your app can open the links.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.oncall.android.activity.ExternalLinksHandlerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="test.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/user"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In your activity onCreate handle the intent that will come. You can call onNewIntent with your Intent and handle it onNewIntent. There you extract the data that you need, in my case I start MainActivity and leave it to operate with the data.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     onNewIntent(getIntent());
 }

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && data != null) {
        startMainActivity(data);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/server) is what you should do with your website. You have to add some tags to it, it's not rocket science.